# Does the png file contain string `0.0.0.0`?

Tags: grep, binary

I had upload the png file into my dropbox,you can download as `/tmp/mount.png` to reproduce my output.
[mount.png in my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv8yp6sz6u6xezo/mount.png?dl=0)

man grep :

```
 -a, --text
          Process a binary file as if it were text
```

Search '0.0.0.0' in a png file with grep.

```
grep -a  "0.0.0.0"  /tmp/mount.png
```

[image]
I have never seen `0.0.0.0` by eye.
Does the png file contains string `0.0.0.0` really?

The hex value of `0.0.0.0` is :

```
echo -n '0.0.0.0' |xxd
00000000: 302e 302e 302e 30                        0.0.0.0
```

Let's search it with hex value:

```
xxd  /tmp/mount.png |grep '302e302e302e30'
```

Nothing you can get.

```
xxd  /tmp/mount.png |grep '302e'
```

Nothing you can get too.

Does the png file contain string `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: If you need to match a literal period in a regular expression, you must escape it with a backslash. In your particular case, with a fixed string to match, you could get away with `grep -F` as suggested in the Correct Answer; but in a more general case, where you would try to match any digits, for example, not just `0`, you would need regular expressions, and escaping the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It contains the string `00000008` part of which matches the regex `0.0.0.0`. In a regex `.` matches any character, including `0`.

To match the literal string `0.0.0.0` you can use `fgrep` or the `-F` argument to grep.